# How do I pronounce "11-14 March"?

Tags: pronunciation, dates

How do I pronounce the bold part? Should I include "to", for example?

> During the fighting of **11-14 March** they were pounded repeatedly by Ukrainian artillery while trying to force their way into the town of Bucha, scene of gruesome subsequent crimes against local civilians.

Comment: I think this is partly a matter of opinion, but I would probably read it out loud as "the eleventh through the fourteenth of March".

Comment: Definitely largely opinion based; my inclination would be to read it as either "March eleventh to fourteenth" or "eleventh to fourteenth [of] March"

Comment: In Britain we would be likely to say "eleventh to fourteenth of March".

Comment: An alternative is "the eleventh to the fourteenth of March", with an explicit "the" before each ordinal number.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether British or US English. US media usage would likely be "the eleventh to fourteenth of March," and *perhaps* a UK alternative might be, "eleventh through fourteenth March," although either might invert the order to ""March eleventh to/through fourteenth of March."

Logically, the inclusive "through" is likely meant, but "to" (up to but *not* including the end date) has come to be used as "through". Mathematicians would be appalled at that, though. [A ray is not a segment is not a line](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/lines-segments-rays), whatever is claimed about roses by Stein.

Comment: The other way round - US uses _through_, UK doesn't.

Comment: @KateBunting are you American? How do you hear it pronounced on the TV, for instance?

Comment: I'm not American, but @stangdon, who is, says in a comment above that they would say it like that. I would say 'the eleventh to the fourteenth of March'.

Comment: "the inclusive "through" is likely meant, but "to" (up to but not including the end date) has come to be used as "through". You imply that "to" used to be used only in the exclusive sense. What evidence is there for this? I've never come across "to" used that way. You gloss the inclusive sense of "to" as "through" as if "through" is more familiar or had this sense earlier. "To" has long had this sense, and to anyone but an American, this usage of "through" might well come across as an Americanism.

Comment: This is probably not American English; the text would likely be written "March 11-14" if it was. It's very rare that I (an American) see the day written before the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [en dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) between dates as either **to** or **through**, with one or the other being used depending on context. In your specific case you'd say **through**.